# Exception propagation from one service to another in spring Boot - Microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

How to propagate exceptions from one microservice to another in the spring Boot application.

ex-the below code will throw the expection ResourceNotFoundException and want to catch the same exception in another service calling this api.

```java
@GetMapping("/patients/{patientId}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> retrievePatientById(@PathVariable Long patientId) {
    Optional<PatientEntity> optionalPatient = patientRepo.findById(patientId);
    if (optionalPatient.isPresent()){
        PatientEntity patientEntity=optionalPatient.get();
        ApiResponse apiResponse=new ApiResponse();
        apiResponse.setData(patientEntity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(apiResponse);
    }
    else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Patient","Id",String.valueOf(patientId));
    }
}
```

and this api is only throwing one exception what if it throw more than one exception how to catch all in another service with same message

```java
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> resourceError(ResourceNotFoundException e){
    CareConnectException careConnectException=new                    CareConnectException("1002",e.getMessage(),
            "You are entering wrong details please check them ");
    ApiResponse apiResponse=new ApiResponse();
    apiResponse.setError(careConnectException);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}

catch (FeignException e) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Patient", "Id", String.valueOf(patientId));
    }
```

I tried this but its not looking good to catch more than one exception

Comment: Please note that the caller service is not going to capture the exception as a "java" exception. It will see the exception as an HTTP response with a body and status. It's your job as the caller to map that to an application-level exception if you want to. You're not calling a Java method, but rather a REST API

Comment: @AllanJuan means like this
catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) 
            String errorMessage = ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
            System.out.println("**********************************"+errorMessage);
        }

Comment: @AllanJuan ????